# Oracle & EF Core BoolToTwoValuesConverter not Converter-ing

Tags: oracle, ef-core-2.2, valueconverter

I have created a simple `BoolToTwoValuesConverter<int>` so when there's a `-1` in the database column it'll convert to `false`, and `0` converts to `true`:

```cs
var falseNegOneTrueZero = new BoolToTwoValuesConverter<int>(-1, 0);
```

I've mapped my Property with that converter:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>(entity => 
{
   entity.Property(e => e.IsWhatever)
         .HasColumnName("CRYPTIC_COL_NM")
         .HasColumnType(number(1,0))
         .HasConversion(falseNegOneTrueZero);

    // etc...
}

// example of using the property in a query

return summaries.Where(s => s.IsWhatever);
```

but whenever I try to use the column in my query, it chokes hard:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'.
>      at **Oracle**.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleBoolTypeMapping.GenerateNonNullSqlLiteral(Object value)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)

I've also tried it the "verbose" way by specifying a conversion like this:

```cs
   entity.Property(e => e.IsWhatever)
         .HasColumnName("CRYPTIC_COL_NM")
         .HasColumnType(number(1,0))
         .HasConversion(
               // 0 is true, -1 is false
              entityValue => entityValue ? 0 : -1,
              dbValue => dbValue == 0);
```

... to no avail.  I'm running out of ideas, any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `.HasColumnType()` statement made the problem go away.  I don't like it, but it worked:

```
entity.Property(e => e.IsWhatever)
     .HasColumnName("CRYPTIC_COL_NM")
     .HasConversion(falseNegOneTrueZero);
```